# Derivation of a graph of the cosine function from a graph of the sine function using definitions from the group theory

Tags: group-theory

I believe it must be possible to obtain one from another using a group action ($ℝ:ℝ^ℝ$)and conceptions of the group theory(and maybe some bits from the set theory as long as $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ is concerned). I'm rather new to the these matters and I don't know how to unravel the task. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Who gave you this task?

Comment: My high school professor. I took his algebra course. As for the task, I'm quite sure it is valid and I guess it has something to do with geometrical translation(from the point of view of the set theory).

Comment: Are you sure he said set theory? Maybe he meant group theory?

Comment: Yes, he must have meant that. I was having a misconception that the group theory is a part of the set theory, which is not the case.

Comment: So what are "the definitions of set theory"?

Comment: Now that you've corrected me I'm sure he must've meant "conceptions of the group theory".

Comment: Okay then. My job here is done, then. :-)

Comment: Isn't just $\cos(x) = \sin(x+\pi/2)$ i.e. translate the sine over a distance $\pi/2$ to the left?

Comment: @Andreas, thanks for the information. It is interesting for me even though we didn't have theta functions like that in our curriculum and it appears that I'll have to get along without it for this task. 
Han, thank you too. It surely is. But is has to be done in terms of group theory and that action on RR.

Comment: The group theory comes from the action of $\mathbb{R}$ on itself (and then on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$, acting on the argument) via translations. It's that formula, as mentioned by @HandeBruijn, anyway.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti, Thanks a lot for this clarification! But how exactly does it correspond to the formula? I think I "feel" it but I can't prove it. Could you please elaborate?